# How do I add params to a createAPI in RTK Redux Toolkit?

Tags: react-redux

This is what my createAsyncThunk looks like

```
  export const fetchMapData = createAsyncThunk(
  'mapdata/fetchMapData', 
  async (id) => { 
    const response = await axios.get(
      GLOBALVIEWS_API,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-API-KEY': HBO_KEY,
        },
        params: {
          titleId: id,
        }
      }
    )

    return response.data.Item;
  }
)
```

and I need to turn that into a createApi() but this below is still failing at the param requirement

```
 export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      headers.set('X-API-KEY', HBO_KEY)
      return headers
    }
  }),
  endpoints:(builder) => ({
    getMedia: builder.query({
      query:(id) => {
        console.log("titleId: ", id);
        return{
          url: '/titlestest',
          params: {titleId: id}
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      headers.set('X-API-KEY', HBO_KEY)
      return headers
    }
  }),
  endpoints:(builder) => ({
    getMedia: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `/titletest/${id}`,
      // or
      query: (id) => ({ url: `/titletest/${id}` }),
      // or
      query: ({ title, id }) => `/${title}/${id}`,
    })
  })
})
```